# getting stuck on storing data into array variables

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to add some data into one array variable in PowerShell. but it is showing error like *"Index was outside the bounds of the array"*. What I have is:

```
$test = @()
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 20; $i++)
{
    $test[$i] = $i
}
$test
```

And it is showing error that *"Index was outside the bounds of the array"*.

Is there any way in PowerShell to store the data into an array variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$test = @()
for($i = 0 ; $i -lt 20; $i++)
{
    $test += $i
}
$test
```

`$test[$i]` is one of the elements of the array and obviously if you are trying to store 20 elements there, it is bound to give you `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception. Use the `+=` operator to add values to an existing array.
After you are done storing the elements, you can access individual elements of the array like `$test[0]..$test[19]` (since an array's index start from `0`).

Answer (score 3):

`$test = @()` is a dynamically sized array. If you want to use that you need to append to it in the loop:

```
$test = @()
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
    $test += $i
}
```

or (better):

```
$test = @(for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
    $i
})
```

or (even better, at least in this particular scenario):

```
$test = 0..19
```

If you want to assign values via indexed access you need to define the array with a fixed size:

```
$test = New-Object Object[] (20)
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
    $test[$i] = $i
}
```

or pre-load a dynamically sized array with the desired number of elements:

```
$test = 1..20 | ForEach-Object { $null }
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
    $test[$i] = $i
}
```